# Modules for handling excel specific formatting

Tags: python

Does anyone know of any good Python modules for handling excel specific formatting? For example color coding cells or changing font size, or perhaps even more complicated stuff like pre-generating a pivot table etc. Would be handy to know for generating reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several; `xlsxwriter` is a good one.  That's what `pandas` uses.  https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Technically, this is not a good StackOverflow question and I should be scolded or answering it.